# Сортировка вставками,в чем проблема

Tags: c

```
int main(void){
int i, j, n;
printf("Enter the number of lines and columns\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
int tmp;
int array[n][n];
printf("unsorted array\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0;j < n;j++){
        array[i][j] = 10 + rand()% (20-10+1);
        printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);
    }
    puts("\n");
}
printf("sorted array\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0;j < n; i++){
        tmp = array [i][i];
        array[i][i] = array[j][j];
        array[j][j] = tmp;
    }
    
}
for (i = 0;i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0;j < n;j++){
        printf("%d\t",array[i][j]);
    }
    puts("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Программа не заходит дальше "sorted array" в чем проблема? Тут я попробовал реализовать сортировку главной диагонали,по заданию так же нужны параллельные побочной и главной,как это сделать?

Comment: Цикл `for(j = 0;j < n; i++)` никогда не закончится, поэтому дальше программа и не идёт

Comment: упс,изменил.заработало,но не много не так.Сортирует не до конца,из за чего? можете объяснить если не сложно

Comment: Если честно, я тут не вижу абсолютно никакой сортировки... Сортировка подразумевает хотя бы один if, а у вас тут ни одного

Comment: из поиска я смог найти только вот такое подобие сортировки через for

Comment: Почему бы не взять любую книжку по алгоритмам или найти страничку с описанием и кодом сортировки вставками? Их сотни. То, что в коде подразумевалось - напоминает пузырёк, а не вставки.